# first time install on vertual box, black screen

Tags: system-installation, startup

I had just installed ubuntu on virtual box, booting it first time took me to a black screen, it also has a horizontal text line, although whatever I type nothing happenes

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Your *computer* boots to a black screen, or *the virtual machine* boots to a black screen? Which version of Ubuntu is in the VM, and what is the operating system used by the host machine? Without this information, it will be almost impossible to provide any reasonable suggestions.

Comment: ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: and the virtual machine boots to a black screen, not the computer, I use virtual box

Comment: The Virtualbox forums are good for this kind of question. This is a link to a search for black screen in the Linux guests forum. https://forums.virtualbox.org/search.php?keywords=Black+screen+&fid%5B0%5D=3